A multiplicatively/inversely unclosed set in a group
Question
Let $G$ be a group, is there a subset $S$(multiplicatively unclosed set) such that: $\forall x,y \in S, xy \notin S$? Is there a subset $S$(inversely unclosed set) such that: $\forall x \in S, x^{-1} \notin S$? Is there a subset $S$ such that: $\forall x \in S, y \in G -\{e\}, xy \notin S$?
For cyclic groups, finding such a set is easy: $G=\langle a\rangle,a^2 \ne e$, then $\{a\}$ is the set that satisfies all three of the above.
I want to know, for what group must there be a set that satisfies one of the three above?

For any subset $S$, $\forall x\in S$, $id_G \in G$, $xid_G=x \in S$.

A group satisfies the first property if and only it is nontrivial. Indeed, if $a$ is an element of $G$ different from $1$, then $a^2 \not= a$ and one can take $S = \{a\}$.
A group satisfies the second property if and only it is not of exponent $2$. Indeed, if $a$ is an element of $G$ such that $a^2 \not= 1$, then $a^{-1} \not= a$ and one can take $S = \{a\}$. By the way, the groups of exponent $2$ are isomorphic to the additive group of a vector space over the field ${\Bbb F}_2$.
A group satisfies the third property if and only it is nontrivial.
Indeed, if $a$ is an element of $G$ different from $1$, then  $ab \not= a$ for all $b \in G \setminus \{1\}$, and one can take $S = \{a\}$.
